# Please help me regarding this application logic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I have to build such application in which i have to use the database for storing data.
In First screen following functionality i have to done:
First of all i have to write something in to the TextBox, On submitting of that text Box value , I have to record one Sound File.
After Completing that, one test is created.
On clicking of that test, the recorded sound is played, And User have to write text in to the Empty text box value. If the previously Text Box value with that sound is match, then user should be notified with the 1 point.

So how can it be possible to store text value and the Sound file ? And how i implement to check what i have recorded while entering the text value in to the text box ??
Please Help me regarding this.
Thanks.

Edited Question:

Its some what test type application.  example like : In Which i have to record "banana" by saying word and also have to entered text like banana in text box. and it should be save as like test1. Now after that in second screen while i click on test1, it should be sound like banana, and in text box i have to entered "banana" as text. if i entered any other word then it will give me wrong answer that the text not matched with the sound.

Comment: Can you please write what the application is abt..

Comment: its a question. Its some what puzzle type application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Performing Audio Capture at the bottom of [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) for recording, and above it for playback.  You can write your sound files to the local storage and put the matching word and the location of the soundfile in a local [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).  (A look at Android's [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) might help with the SQLite part.)

Comment: Ok thanks for reply. I will try on it. And if getting any trouble then will inform you. Thanks again.